# Recursive search for files that hold some specific text

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, debian, recursive

How do I recursively generate a text file which has a list of all files on my server which contain a specific string anywhere in the files?

I know the following command can be used to replace a string recursively

```
find /var/www -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/old string/new string/g'
```

I do not want to replace the string, I just want a list of all files which contain the string.

Comment: For a windows user I would have suggested to writes a batch file which saves the output to a file and put it in the scheduler . Try whatever is the linux substitute for this process

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `grep` instead of `sed`:

```
find /var/www -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i 'old string'
```

From the way you phrase the question, it seems like you're not yet too familiar with `grep`. Read more about its options in its man page type: `man grep` at your command line.

**update to answer comment** -- try adding the `-l` option to show just file names. The `-i` makes the search case insensitive. The easy to use both is with a single dash: `grep -il`

Comment: This does not seem to give me just the paths/files containing the string I am looking for.  For some reason, I am also getting the text from the files searched too.

Comment: Added bit about `-l`

Answer (score 4):

You can also use grep alone without find:

```
grep -Rli 'old string' /var/www > list_of_files
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the -l flag to the command to only list the file names

```
find /var/www -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -li 'old string'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ack -- it's faster than grep and supports perl regex.

```
ack -la <pattern> /var/www
```

On some systems this package is called "ack" and sometimes its called "ack-grep".